# screen fails with "WriteMessage: Bad file descriptor"

Tags: gnu-screen

I have screen session "main", started in `/dev/ttySAC0` and sh, started in `/dev/ttySAC0` (outside screen session) with input, output and error streams, redirected to pseudoterminal `/dev/pts/1`.
When I attach to /dev/pts/1 terminal and try to run `screen -r main`, it fails with:

`WriteMessage: Bad file descriptor`

But creating new screen session with `screen` works fine. Furthermore, if I run `screen -r main` in this screen session, I got screen with my saved session in another screen session. It's not usefull, but it's works.

Even if I starts new session in `/dev/pts/1`, detatch from it and try to revive it, I got same error.

Answer (score 7):

Run `screen -d`, find the screens and run `screen -R [screen_name]`.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the line `defnonblock on` to your ~/.screenrc file.

When I began having the same problem I found a few posts mentioning that it fixed their issues. It fixed mine.

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It happens if I have a screen with the same name as another screen + more text after it, the screen name without the extra text breaks, ie

```
~$ screen -ls
        7385.foo-screen      (02/27/2020 12:03:41 AM)        (Detached)
        7296.foo-screen-2    (02/27/2020 12:00:48 AM)        (Detached)
```

works:

```
~$ screen -r foo-screen-2
```

fails:

```
~$ screen -r foo-screen 
WriteMessage: Bad file descriptor
```

works:

```
~$ screen -r 7385.foo-screen
```